# Does the scheduling method post SQL 2016 depend on the database compatibility level?

Tags: sql-server, architecture

> up to SQL Server 2014 (12.x), Worker 1 is allowed to basically
> monopolize the scheduler by having more overall quantum time. Starting
> with SQL Server 2016 (13.x), cooperative scheduling includes Large
> Deficit First (LDF) scheduling.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/thread-and-task-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-task-scheduling

Is the above default behaviour in  SQL 2016+ or does it depend on the database compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2):

It will not depend on the database compatibility level.

Compatibility level (I know you mentioned mode and I assume you meant level) is a database level setting and not server level.

> The database compatibility level setting provides backward
> compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server in what relates to
> Transact-SQL and query optimization behaviors only for the specified
> database, not for the entire server.
>
> Database compatibility level also provides backward compatibility with
> earlier versions of SQL Server, because databases attached or restored
> from any earlier version of SQL Server retain their existing
> compatibility level (if same or higher than the minimum allowed
> compatibility level). This was discussed in the Using compatibility
> level for backward compatibility section of this article.

Ref: [ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL) compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver15)